# Using sp.ndimage.label on Xarray DataArray with apply_ufunc

Tags: python, python-xarray, ndimage

Lets say I have the simple array:

```
data = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1]
```

I can apply labeling to this data with the scipy ndimage module with:

```
groups, _ = sp.ndimage.label(data)
```

Resulting in

```
In [68]: print(groups)
[1 1 0 0 2 2 2]
```

Now, I would like to do the same labeling function on a  xarray DataArray.

```
xr_data = xr.DataArray([1,1,0,0,1,1,1], coords = [("x", [0,1,2,3,4,5,6])])
```

I know I could call the same function as before on the `xr_data`, but the output of doing this call is a numpy array, which in my actual dataset, is too large to fit in memory.

It seems like the `xr.apply_ufunc` function is what I need. However, I am having trouble getting it to work.

```
def xr_label(arr):
    return xr.apply_ufunc(sp.ndimage.label, arr)

xr_groups, _ = xr_label(xr_data)
```

This results in:
"**ValueError**: applied function returned data with unexpected number of dimensions. Received 0 dimension(s) but expected 1 dimensions with names: ('x',)"

I'm finding the documentation on the apply_ufunc method difficult to interpret. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define `input_core_dims` and `output_core_dims` as parameters to `apply_ufunc`. See the documentation at: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html

In your case I think this will be:

```
xr.apply_ufunc(sp.ndimage.label, arr, input_core_dims=[['x']], output_core_dims=[['x']])
```

I also recently struggled with understanding `apply_ufunc` (to be fair, I still don't have a full understanding), however the example at http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/apply_ufunc_vectorize_1d.html helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks! The only modification I had to make was adding another empty list to the output dimensions: `output_core_dims=[['x'], []]`, because the label function also returns two things - a array with each element labels, and a single integer giving the number of groups found.